# Roles en laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

Actualmente soy nueva trabajando con laravel 5.7 y estoy trabajando con un login personalizado... actualmente el login me ingresa, pero tengo tres usuarios y necesito que dependiendo del rol me inicie sesión y me redireccione a la vista de cada uno.

El cotrolador del login lo tengo así:

```
public function LoginUsuario()
{

    $credenciales = $this->validate(request(),
    [
        'email'=>'email',
        'password'=>'required',

    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt($credenciales))
    {
        return 'Login Ok';
    }
    else{
        return back()
        ->withErrors(['email'=>trans('auth.failed')])
        ->withInput(request(['email']));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se como tengas elaborado tus **modelos** de `User` y `Role`, pero deberias tener una relacion entre ellos:

**Model User**

```
public function role() {
            return $this->belongsTo( Roles::class, 'role_id' );
        }
```

**Model Role**

```
public function user() {
            return $this->hasMany( User::class, 'role_id' );
        }
```

Suponiendo que tu pagina `login` sea `("/")`, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma dentro de archivo de ruta **web.php**:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(!Auth::guest()) {

        if(Auth::user()->role->nombre == 'tecnico'){ 

            return view('vista-tecnico');
        }
        if(Auth::user()->role->nombre == 'admin'){

            return view('vista-admin');   
        }

    }else
        return view('auth.login');
});
```

Espero que esto sea de ayuda.